# Display problems in IE - Datatables row grouping

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, datatables, grouping

I am using Datatables Collapsible/Expandable Grouping with a rowcount per group, expand/collapse all buttons and a reset search button.  I've encountered some display problems with Internet Explorer.

In IE 9, IE 8 and IE 7 the reset search button (a black X to the right of the search field) is not being displayed.

In IE 7 Search field and label are also displayed incorrectly.  It is not right aligned.

Can anyone help me to resolve these IE CSS issues?  Your help would be greatly appreciated!

I've set up a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/gtgzr/

Answer (score 0):

**1. In IE 9, IE 8 and IE 7 the reset search button is not being displayed.**

You are using `<input type="image" ... />` with no src attribute. Yes the containing box does contain icons but they are background-images declared by CSS, not directly rendered from a src attribute in the input element, IE will not play nice with your syntax.

**2. In IE 7 Search field and label are also displayed incorrectly. It is not right aligned.**

It is not right aligned as IE7 requires the element to have at least some styling to position it properly. You have floated the expand all button left and the reset button right, to fix this in IE7 you can either do away with floats entirely and use "display:inline-block; position:relative" to position the elements inline. Or keep using floats but float the search box right as well. (You will need to switch the positions of the reset box and the search box in the sDOM attribute to maintain correct positioning when right floating.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I've reworked my jsfiddle and it now works everywhere EXCEPT... IE 7.

Here is my revised jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/SG8Dm/2/

Comment: It seems that calling the function ResetSearchField(); is the offending source.